# MYSQL MULTIPLE TABLE JOIN USING pattern match / JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a multi table select statement in mysql to filter query from some user inputs. The input $_POST values are:  1.zipcode [from locations table] or 2.city [from locations table] and/or 3.on_date [from calendar table] and /or 4.title [from posts table].

```
FROM table_many
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.title LIKE '%{$title}%'
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.user_id
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.post_id = posts.post_id AND locations.city = '$city[0]'
LEFT JOIN calendar ON calendar.post_id = posts.post_id AND calendar.on_date = '$date'
LEFT JOIN uploads ON posts.post_id = uploads.post_id 
WHERE table_many.cat_id = '$row_cat[0]' AND table_many.post_id = posts.post_id";
```

This setup works for the locations. I can enter either a zipcode or a city and the query filters correctly, but the $date and $title values, which are set from the input, retrieve no records.

Any ideas? or do you need more info? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably the date formats are different :) can you show what date formats you have.. or you can use `date_format()` to format dates into one common format.

Comment: `%{title}%` is missing a `$`...

Comment: date formats i use in the input are the same as in the column format

Answer (score 0):

You left out tableName in title `INNER JOIN posts ON title LIKE '%{$title}%'`

try 
`tableName.title`.

I don't see anything with the query that will make it not work, but lemme have a look at it again

Comment: yeah, i have posts.title LIKE in my code.  i was wondering if i can use like in the ON statement?